# Postgres SELECT * from large table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Working with a Postgres table containing large records, nearly 7m. I understand `SELECT * FROM table` is large enough to fit in memory, so db connection is lost after a long delay waiting for query result (can only execute `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT n`).

I need to process each record going through sequentially until the last. What is the way to do this?

Comment: You should see if you can do this work in the database.  Why do you need to process each record individually in the application?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to fetch each record and send (to an application) as JSON.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you run that statement? Which Programming language are you using? How are you planning to handle 7 million JSON values in your application?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is a one-time upload of previously collected environmental datasets, that I want to do to a different platform (FIWARE precisely). Because the dataset isn't in the FIWARE standards, each record should be processed to conform to FIWARE model before forwarding to a publish/subscribe application on the FIWARE platform.

Comment: I don't think the delay is caused by `waiting for the query result`, Instead, it is probaly  caused by the *application* , processing the first few records, and not reading the rest. You can test this by dumping to .csv or .tsv and work from there.

Comment: @wildplasser Actually I tested without the processing step, using simple `SELECT *` to see, which proved to be the case.  After about 1min or so, the connection get killed without returning query results.

Comment: Using which frontend? BTW: could be a network/firewall issue, or ssl renegotiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can get in chunks of n records.**

```
select * from table where tableId>currentTableId and tableId<currentTableId*chunk_size
```

**Explation:**

Lets say you have 100 records and your memory contains 10 records at a time.

you query for execute 10 time from your application(any ORM)

```
 int totalRecords = executeQuery('select count(*) from table');
    int chunkSize = 10;
    int chunks = totalRecords/chunkSize ;
    while(chuks>0){
    executeQuery('select * from table where tableId>currentTableId and tableId<currentTableId*chunkSize ');
chunk-=chunkSize;
    }
```

This code is in a very abstract way. It's just a hint for you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please add a little explanation to this?